# Using Bash to search files for

Tags: bash, grep

I have two text files, 1 with a unique list of IP addresses and the other with a longer list of an IP address population. I am trying to identify what IP addresses from the unique list appear in the longer population list using bash.

So far I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
    while read line; do
        grep -Ff "$line" population.txt
done < $uniqueIP.txt
```

The script runs but I get no output. I am trying to count the number of occurrences but having issues coming up with the logic. Currently, the script does not output anything.

**Sample Input:**

uniqueIP.txt

```
192.168.1.10
192.168.1.11
192.168.1.12
192.168.1.13
192.168.1.14
```

population.txt

```
192.168.1.12
192.168.1.14
192.168.1.15
192.168.1.16
192.168.1.17
192.168.1.18
192.168.1.19
192.168.1.22
192.168.1.23
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Found: 192.168.1.12
Found: 192.168.1.14
Total: 2
```

Comment: `grep -f` takes _the file_, not lines in the file.

Comment: Just use `grep -Fx -f uniqueIP.txt population.txt`

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: uniqueIP.txt - 192.168.1.10,192.168.1.11,192.168.1.12, 192.168.1.13, 192.168.1.14
population - 192.168.1.12, 192.168.1.14,192.168.1.15, 192.168.1.16, 192.168.1.17, 192.168.1.18, 192.168.1.19, 192.168.1.22, 192.168.1.23
Output: 
Found: 192.168.1.12
Found: 192.168.1.14
Total: 2

Comment: What's your field separator? Newline, comma or comma followed by one space?

Comment: Why don't you put each IP on its own line? This format makes it harder to process.

Comment: Sorry yes, it would be a new line instead of a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggested bash function `count_unique_ips` for your problem

```
#!/bin/bash

function count_unique_ips()
{
  local unique_ips_file=$1
  local population_file=$2

  local unique_ip_list=$(tr ' ' '\n' < ${unique_ips_file} | sort | uniq)

  for ip in "${unique_ip_list[@]}"; do
    count=$(grep -o -i ${ip} ${population_file} | wc -l)
    echo "'${ip}': ${count}"
  done
}

count_unique_ips uniqueIP.txt population.txt
```

You should get the following output based on 2 given input files `uniqueIP.txt` and `population.txt`

```
'192.168.1.10':        0
'192.168.1.11':        0
'192.168.1.12':        1
'192.168.1.13':        0
'192.168.1.14':        1
```

Comment: What if one of those filenames contains spaces...?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question by giving an example?

Comment: What does the command unique_ip_list=$(tr ' ' '\n' < ${unique_ips_file} | sort | uniq) do excatly and if the list is already uniq wouldnt running the 'uniq' command be an extra step that is not needed? As well as sort? Is sort needed even though the population would not be sorted?

Comment: This line basically reads the first input file `uniqueIP.txt` and returns the list of unique IP addresses in order. If you are 100% sure the list is unique and you do not want to sort it then you can simply remove the part `| sort | uniq`.

Comment: I keep getting 'grep: 192.168.1.10: No such file or directory' when I attempt to execute the script. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: It seems the `population.txt` file is not found. If you use exactly the script I provided, you should put 2 files `uniqueIP.txt` and `population.txt` in the same directory as the bash script.

Answer (score 0):

A short method, using only `grep`, could be

```
grep -Fxf uniqueIP.txt population.txt
```

but this would be slow for large files. A faster way is

```
sort uniqueIP.txt population.txt | uniq -d
```

assuming the IPs in population.txt are also unique within this file, and one IP per line without extra characters (including blank characters).